# How to program an html page to move to a new web page on user's clicking an item of an embedded flash movie?

Tags: flash

Let me ask how to program an html page to move to a new web page on user's clicking an item of an embedded flash movie?
But , in detail, I actually want to do a little different thing. I want that the parent html page remains there ,instead I want a child html frame has a new page after user's clicking the list item of the embedded flash movie.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: AS2 or AS3? Either way, to target a frame on the parent HTML page you pass the name of the frame in the `target` parameter of your call.

Comment: @shanethehat,thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an individual element in the Flash animation, use getURL("http://...") with the onClick mouseEvent in Flash.

As for the 'child' html frame, adding target="_blank" to an anchor tag will open the link in a new tab. If you wanted it in an iframe you could alter the iframe src.

Comment: ,could you please give me the full namespace path to the function ,getURL,in Flash builder? I got an error which says that getURL is undefined.

Comment: @shanethehat 's post below explains it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The principle of targeting frames works the same in Flash as it does on an HTML page.  In HTML, to load a page into a specific frame you use the `target` attribute:

```
<a href="myPage.html" target="childFrame">text</a>
```

Flash also supports the `target` attribute, although it works slightly differently in AS1/2 and AS3:

**AS1/2**

```
getURL("myPage.html","childFrame");
```

**AS3**

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("myPage.html"), "childFrame");
```